# Testing for undefined in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want to run a code only if the `argument[0].recordCount` is greater than zero or is NOT undefined. However, the code is ran when the `argument[0].recordCound` alert shows undefined.

```
if(arguments[0].recordCount > 0 && 
   arguments[0].recordCount !== 'undefined')
{ //if more than 0 records show in bar
                            
    document.getElementById('totalRecords').innerHTML = 
       arguments[0].recordCount + " Records";
}
```

How can I test for undefined here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using `undefined` as a string you need to do so with the `typeof` operator.

Also, you should be checking if it's defined *before* any other checks on the property.

```
if ( 'undefined' != typeof arguments[0].recordCount && arguments[0].recordCount > 0 )
```

Comment: +1. Probably the `!==` operator should be used instead of `!=` ?

Comment: stakx: no. `typeof` is guaranteed to return a string, and you're comparing its return value to another string, so it'll always be fine, no matter what Crockfordian habits you may have learned :)

Comment: @stakx - irrelevent.  `typeof` returns a string.

Comment: @Tim: You're right. It's become quite a persistent habit, whenever I see a `==` or `!=` I think it should be the strict operators instead.

Comment: Possibly-relevant performance comparison of `typeof var` vs `=== undefined` (the latter being faster than the former) http://jsperf.com/type-of-undefined-vs-undefined

Answer (score 3):

`undefined` is a <del>keyword</del> a global variable with constant value, use it without quotes:

```
if(arguments[0].recordCount > 0 && arguments[0].recordCount !== undefined)
```

But actually it would be sufficient to test only the first condition:

```
if(arguments[0].recordCount > 0)
```

because if `recordCount` is larger than zero, it is defined anyway.

---

More common is to switch the conditions and test *first* whether it is defined, to avoid possible errors in the following tests (not sure if this is necessary here):

```
if(arguments[0].recordCount !== undefined && arguments[0].recordCount > 0)
```

Comment: Right, if you insist in comparing it as a `'string'`, use `!=` instead of `!==`. The former just tests the value, while the latter tests **both** the type and value.

Comment: `undefined` is *not* a keyword in JavaScript. However, `typeof(x)` will return the string `"undefined"` if `x` is undefined.

Comment: `undefined` can be changed. you shouldn't be comparing against it. if `recordCount` is not guaranteed to have some value when you do the comparison, it's going to blow up.

Answer (score 1):

To check for a variable to be not null and not undefined,

`if(thatVariable)` is enough though implicit conversion can cause problem for some cases where thatVariable is empty string, or a boolean, or number 0. If implicit conversion is not the case for our variable, the following would do,

```
if(arguments[0].recordCount && arguments[0].recordCount > 0)
```

But the following would be problematic,

```
if(arguments[0].recordCount !== undefined && arguments[0].recordCount > 0)
```

Consider,

```
var undefined = 'surprise' //possible since undefined is not a keyword
if(arguments[0].recordCount !== undefined && arguments[0].recordCount > 0)
```

Now this 'if' will break even though recordCount is undefined.

One more thing: `if(a != null)` will also check undefined due to implicit conversion. Hence `if(a != null && a != undefined)` is redundant